# Xamarin Multiple framework target

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, multitargeting

Good morning

I am building package for Xamrin.Forms. I follow how its done by [James Montenango](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/GeolocatorPlugin/tree/master/src/Geolocator.Plugin)

Here are some important pieces of my .csproj

```
<TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;MonoAndroid10.0;Xamarin.iOS10</TargetFrameworks>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="**\*.shared.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup Condition=" $(TargetFramework.StartsWith('netstandard')) ">
    <PackageReference Include="XTricks.Shared" Version="1.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Essentials" Version="1.6.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup Condition=" $(TargetFramework.StartsWith('MonoAndroid')) ">
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Forms" Version="5.0.0.2196" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Location" Version="118.0.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="XTricks.Shared" Version="1.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Essentials" Version="1.6.1" />
    <Compile Include="**\*.android.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup Condition=" $(TargetFramework.StartsWith('Xamarin.iOS')) ">
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Essentials" Version="1.6.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="XTricks.Shared" Version="1.0.1" />
    <Compile Include="**\*.apple.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Everything is working except one important thing.
I would like to have two implementation of the same class for Android and for iOS.

For this purpose I declare and interface as:

```
IMyService.shared.cs
```

And I create two classes, one in Android folder called:
MyService.android.cs which implements IMyService.shared.cs
and second in Apple folder called MyService.apple.cs.

Now as is done in above library I would like to use service in shared code.

```
        private static IMyService Service
        {
            get
            {
#if NETSTANDARD1_0 || NETSTANDARD2_0
                return null;
#else
                return new MyService(); // And this code is red one. MyService cannot be found. 
#endif
            }
        }
```

Basically I am stucked there. Does anyone know how to move foward?

Comment: Does [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction) help? Dependency Injection is the easiest way to resolve a platform-specific service class.

Comment: @AndrewH thank you, however its not solution for this problem

Comment: It's exactly the solution as you presented the problem: "I would like to have two implementation of the same class for Android and for iOS." If you have a different problem, please update the question.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have same namespace to `MyService` class with your shared codes and then you just build your library.